# Drinking pomegranate juice before Rosh Hashana, does it cancel pomegranate's Shehechayanu blessing?

Tags: halacha, blessing, rosh-hashanah-new-year

If I drink pomegranate juice before Rosh Hashana, does it cancel my whole pomegranate's Shehechayanu blessing? Do I have to bless Shehechayanu before drinking pomegranate juice?

Comment: The classic version of this question is grape juice and grapes OC225:5

Comment: The shulchan aruch discusses the opposite case where you made a shechiyanu on the grapes and then drank the wine. The MB mentions that if you drank the wine and then ate the grapes you would not make another bracha on the grapes. However the question seems to be where he drank the juice and did not make a shechiyanu for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Birchas Habyis (24:29) says that fruit juice isn’t considered as the fruit itself for shechiyanu. Although he’s speaking about making the shechiyanu on the juice, it would seem that it’s not counted as the fruit at all and one could still make the shechiyanu when they eat the fruit.

https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31039&st=&pgnum=131&hilite=